# How to get document extension from a document library in SharePoint 2013 using Client Object Model?

Tags: csom

I tried this code to get value :

```
docEnumerator = collVideoLibrary.getEnumerator();
//Looping through the collection
while (docEnumerator.moveNext()) 
{
    docItem = docEnumerator.get_current();
    var description = docItem.get_item('Title');
}
```

but only "Title" are getting from library, please do needful.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code , To get file name with extension

```
while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var Item = ListEnumerator.get_current();


       fileRef = Item.get_item('FileRef');
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Great ! Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: You can also use `item.get_item("FileLeafRef")` if you want just file name not full path

Comment: Hi  Bhaskar, I need one help, How to Get Active Directory Groups in Sharepoint 2013 using client object model?

Comment: How to get video extension from "Asset Library"?

Comment: I am not sure about active directory , let me check. It will be better if you post this in other question as others can also see it and help.

Comment: Any idea about "Asset Library"....

Comment: Regarding asset library
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965507/sharepoint2013-get-url-of-video-file-from-asset-library-using-rest-jsom

Hope this will help